# Compiler continues to count the borrow as mutable when it is actually immutable

Tags: rust

Consider this code, ignoring the warnings:

```
fn main() {}

pub struct TreeNode {
    subs: Vec<TreeNode>,
}

impl TreeNode {
    pub fn do_something(&mut self) {
        if let Some(changed_node) = self.enum_node(&|_| true) {
            // Closure in real program is much more complicated and it really mutates its parameter
            self.enum_node(&|_| false); // Again, real closure is more complicated
        };
    }

    fn enum_node<'a, F>(&'a mut self, f: &F) -> Option<&'a Self>
    where
        F: Fn(&mut Self) -> bool,
    {
        if f(self) {
            Some(self)
        } else {
            for sub in &mut self.subs {
                if let Some(n) = Self::enum_node(sub, f) {
                    return Some(n);
                }
            }
            None
        }
    }
}
```

The sense of the function `enum_nodes` is to enumerate nodes of the tree, and if the closure `f` returns `true` on some node, stop enumerating and return a reference to that node.

It gives a compiler error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
9  |         if let Some(changed_node) = self.enum_node(&|_| true) {
   |                                     ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |             // Closure in real program is much more complicated and it really mutates its parameter
11 |             self.enum_node(&|_| false); // Again, real closure is more complicated
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
12 |         };
   |         - first borrow ends here
```

I realize that

1. This problem may be solved (I didn't actually try) by using `RefCell`
2. The lifetime of the first borrow of `self` is prolonged because the lifetime of `enum_node`'s `self` parameter and return value are the same, and I assign the return value to the `changed_node`.

If I rewrite lines 9-12 as:

```
self.enum_node(&|_| true);
```

```
self.enum_node(&|_| false);
```

then it compiles because the lifetime of the first borrow of `self` ends immediately after the first call to `enum_node`.

That is not my question.

After the first call to `enum_node` ends, the only way to mutate `self` is via the returned value i.e. `changed_node`, which it is immutable. Why does the compiler continue to count the **borrow as mutable**, is it logical?

How can I understand this behavior of the compiler?

Comment: It should be noted that the OP example works as-is with NLL enabled.

Comment: Pragmatically, it doesn't really matter if it's mutable or immutable. You couldn't get another mutable reference either way.